# logstash plugin for stomp

Tags: plugins, logstash

I am using logstash-1.4.2,  and follow the tutorial here:

http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/contrib-plugins

to install contrib plugins for my stomp.

but when I follow the tutorial in "Automated Installation" part,  run:

```
plugin.sh install contrib
```

I will have the following:

```
C:\logstash\logstash-1.4.2\logstash-1.4.2\bin>plugin.sh install contrib
Welcome to Git (version 1.9.0-preview20140217)


Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.
```

which does not look that my plugins have been added.

Anyone has a solution for this, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The current logstash contrib automated installation only works for Linux/Mac OS, which is why this is failing for you. There are a couple of approaches you can take:

1. There has been some code checked in for doing this on Windows, just
   not yet merged into the production release. Check here:
   https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/pull/1356
2. You can just download and extract the files into your logstash
   directory ( in your case the one above bin). Discussion of that
   approach here:
   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/logstash-users/KbLwrgC4qSk